# Python to update Access not updating

Tags: python, pyodbc, ms-access-2016

I can update an Access Table and pull data into python, BUT I am having an issue doing the opposite:  Updating Access from data I pull into Python.  I am NOT getting any error messages from Python.

Both Python and Access are running at 64

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\dmdil\test_database.accdb;')
cusor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Names_Table (First_Name, Last_Name, Age)
                    VALUES ('Mike', 'Jordan', 55)                 
                    ''')

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Names_Table (First_Name, Last_Name, Age)
                    VALUES ('Mia', 'Morgan', 66)                    
                    ''')

conn.commit()
```

When I execute the above I get no errors.  When I go to my Access table, it's NOT updated.

Comment: `cusor = conn.cursor()` is a typo, it's `cursor` that you then go on to use. That typo is either an issue in transcription into your question, or the other references to `cursor` are actually using some other `cursor` in your namespace

Comment: OMGosh :(,,,,  Thank you so very much.  I am thankful for the help... it works :)